# Struktur des Satzes (Nebensatz)

Tags: subordinate-clause

Beim Lesen eines Buches bin ich auf einen schwierigen Satz gestoßen:

> Das analytische Denken lehrt die Begegnung mit dem Patienten dann
> eigentlich von selbst, wenn der Psychoanalytiker dem Patienten
> gestattet, ihm die Sicht seiner Krankheit vorzutragen, gleich ob der
> Patient mit der Krankheitsgeschichte, der Lebensgeschichte oder
> Kindheitserinnerungen beginnt und *der Psychoanalytiker* **dem** seinerseits
> entsprechend der Regel der gleichschwebenden Aufmerksamkeit unter der
> gleichzeitigen, ebenso vorläufigen Registrierung seiner eigenen
> Gefühle und Eindrücke zu folgen sucht.

1. Ich weiß nicht, ob der kursiv markierte "der Psychoanalytiker" ein Teil des Nebensatzes mit "wenn" ist oder ein Teil des Nebensatzes mit "gleich ob" ist. Weil kein Komma vor "der Psychoanalytiker" steht, dachte ich, dass "der Psychoanalytiker" mit "gleich ob" zusammen gebunden wäre. Aber dann macht der Satz, glaube ich, keinen Sinn, oder?

Kann jemand mir erklären, wie ich den Satz und seine Struktur verstehen soll?

2. Mit welchem Nomen ist der fett markierte Artikel "dem" verbunden?

Comment: Ich möchte anmerken, dass der Satz auch für einen Muttersprachler schwierig ist. Leider gibt es viele Autoren, die ihre Gedanken in möglichst komplexe Grammatik verpacken, auch wenn der Inhalt deutlich einfacher formuliert werden könnte.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Es war schwer zu schreiben, deshalb muss es auch schwer zu lesen sein ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es fehlt aus meiner Sicht ein Komma vor "und", und damit wird es unnötig schwer, den verschiedenen Ebenen von Nebensätzen zu folgen.

Alles ab *", wenn der Psychoanalytiker ..."* gehört zu einem einzigen langen Nebensatz.

Ich verstehe es so, dass der Nebensatz "wenn der Psychoanalytiker dem Patienten gestattet" mit dem zweiten Teil ab *und* fortgesetzt wird: " ..., und der Psychoanalytiker dem seinerseits [...] zu folgen sucht."

Eine verkürzte Form des Wenn-Satzes ist:

> [...], wenn der Psychoanalytiker dem Patienten gestattet, ihm die Sicht seiner Krankheit vorzutragen, [...], und der Psychoanalytiker **dem** seinerseits zu folgen sucht.

Mit "**dem**" ist auf jeden Fall der Vortrag des Patienten oder besser der Vorgang des Vortragens des Patienten gemeint.

Das Komma vor "und" wäre nötig, um den Einschub "gleich ob der Patient mit [...] beginnt" von der Fortsetzung des Wenn-Nebensatzes eine Ebene höher abzugrenzen.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatikalisch betrachtet, ist der Satz mehrdeutig.

Die anderen Antworten haben die Nebensatz-Konstruktion schon analysiert, aber der Hauptsatz ist noch problematisch.

Im Hauptsatz

> Das analytische Denken lehrt die Begegnung mit dem Patienten dann
> eigentlich von selbst, [...]

ist nicht erkennbar, ob "Denken" das Subjekt und "Begegnung" das Objekt ist oder umgekehrt, also ob die Begenung durch das Denken gelehrt wird oder das Denken durch die Begegnung.

- Lernt man, wie man analytisch denkt, wenn man dem Patienten richtig begegnet?
- Oder lernt man, wie man dem Patienten richtig begegnet, wenn man analytisch denkt?

Welche der beiden Interpretationen zutrifft, muss der Leser aus anderer Quelle (Kontext, eigenes Fachverständnis) schlussfolgern.

Answer (score 1):

1. Der Hauptsatz ist hier:

> Das analytische Denken lehrt die Begegnung mit dem Patienten dann eigentlich von selbst

Der gesamte Rest ist der Nebensatz:

> wenn der Psychoanalytiker dem Patienten gestattet, ihm die Sicht seiner Krankheit vorzutragen

Alles was nun folgt, ist eine nachträgliche Erläuterung

> gleich ob der Patient mit der Krankheitsgeschichte, der Lebensgeschichte oder Kindheitserinnerungen beginnt und der Psychoanalytiker dem seinerseits entsprechend der Regel der gleichschwebenden Aufmerksamkeit unter der gleichzeitigen, ebenso vorläufigen Registrierung seiner eigenen Gefühle und Eindrücke zu folgen sucht.

2. *dem* bezieht sich hier auf den Vortrag des Patienten (gleich, ob es sich um die Krankengeschichte, die Lebensgeschichte oder die Kindheitserinnerungen handelt).